# Bijection between sets and Group Structure

Tags: group-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets and $h: X \longrightarrow Y$ a bijection. If $X$ is a group can we make $Y$ to be a group using $f$? I thought about using the group structure in $Y$ for which $h$ is a group isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Define $y \cdot y' = h(h^{-1}(y) \cdot_X h^{-1}(y'))$.